# App crashes on opening error:Unable to start activity Component Info

Tags: android

I was just coded a simple app and when i run it
I got this error

```
2019-05-16 15:12:46.079 6879-6879/net.perkglobal.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: net.perkglobal.myapplication, PID: 6879
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.perkglobal.myapplication/net.perkglobal.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an array: class java.util.ArrayList
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an array: class java.util.ArrayList
        at java.lang.reflect.Array.notAnArray(Array.java:823)
        at java.lang.reflect.Array.get(Array.java:210)
        at net.perkglobal.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:91)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

According to the the error there is error in line 91.So i try changing it but nothing seems to work
can Someone please tell me what i should do

here is a part of code which has the error

```
 TextView text= findViewById(R.id.WP);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("A");
        list.add("B");
        list.add("C");
        list.add("D");
        list.add("E");
        list.add("F");
        list.add("G");
        list.add("H");
        list.add("I");
        list.add("J");
        list.add("K");
        list.add("L");
        list.add("M");
        list.add("N");
        list.add("O");
        list.add("P");
        list.add("Q");
        list.add("R");
        list.add("S");
        list.add("T");
        list.add("U");
        list.add("V");
        list.add("W");
        list.add("X");
        list.add("Y");
        list.add("Z");
        list.add("a");
        list.add("b");
        list.add("c");
        list.add("d");
        list.add("e");
        list.add("f");
        list.add("g");
        list.add("h");
        list.add("i");
        list.add("j");
        list.add("k");
        list.add("l");
        list.add("m");
        list.add("n");
        list.add("o");
        list.add("p");
        list.add("q");
        list.add("r");
        list.add("s");
        list.add("t");
        list.add("u");
        list.add("v");
        list.add("w");
        list.add("x");
        list.add("y");
        list.add("z");
        list.add("1");
        list.add("2");
        list.add("3");
        list.add("4");
        list.add("5");
        list.add("6");
        list.add("7");
        list.add("8");
        list.add("9");
        list.add("0");
        list.add(" ");   for (int n=0 ;n<64;n++){
        String string = Array.get(list,n).toString();
        text.setText(string);}
```

Answer (score -1):

change your for loop to this

```
Iterator i = list.iterator();
  while (i.hasNext()) {
     Log.d("string",i.next())
    //your code goes here
  }
```